# How to set focus to a default child control unless the user clicks on a different child control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a pretty simple use case but I cannot make it work right. I've got a `ListView` whose item template is a `Note` custom `UserControl`:

[image]

Each `Note` has a few simple controls as shown.

I want this to work so that if a row is selected programmatically or by clicking somewhere in it, it sets focus to the first textbox in that row. But if you click on a control in the row, it activates that control (i.e. lets you edit the `Exhibit` contents or click the `Delete` button).

If I don't do anything to set focus, clicking on the row highlights the row but doesn't set focus to any child control.

Within the `Note` control I have tried this:

```
protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);

    text.Focus();
}
```

`text` is the name of that first `TextBox`, and it does set focus, but it also does this if I click directly on the `Exhibit` textbox or `Delete` button, making them unusable.

So, how can I enable the focusing that I want when the container control gets focus, UNLESS it got that focus via a click on a specific child control (which should then keep the focus)?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more searching, I found the correct way to implement this: at the root of the container control (the `Note` `UserControl` in my case), you can specify the name of the control to be the default focus control:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=text}
```

Not sure how I missed that one.